# Understanding Bluescreen minidump from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod, minidumps, windbg

My Windows 7 computer has been suffering from bluescreens that happen soon after booting.

I used Windbg to analyse dumb file of event but I am not sure if I understand what it is telling me.

These lines seem to be interesting:

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT
PROCESS_NAME:  fsgk32.exe
```

Does that indicate that the problem is in drivers or in fsgk32.exe (which is part of F-secure) or in both?

Full result:

```
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (1e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff80002ed05ce, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Parameter 0 of the exception
Arg4: ffffffffffffffff, Parameter 1 of the exception

Debugging Details:
------------------

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800030f7100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800030f71c0
0000000000000000 Nonpaged pool

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced          memory     at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+36e
fffff800`02ed05ce 49890cc0        mov     qword ptr [r8+rax*8],rcx
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1E_c0000005_R
CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT
PROCESS_NAME:  fsgk32.exe
CURRENT_IRQL:  2
ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002f0a738 to fffff80002ebfbc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`060eed48 fffff800`02f0a738 : 00000000`0000001e ffffffff`c0000005         fffff800`02ed05ce 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`060eed50 fffff800`02ebf242 : fffff880`060ef528 fffffa80`0aeff270     fffff880`060ef5d0 fffffa80`0aeff270 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x487ed
fffff880`060ef3f0 fffff800`02ebdb4a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000     00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
fffff880`060ef5d0 fffff800`02ed05ce : fffff700`01080000 fffffa80`0aeff270 fffff800`030fa2c0 fffff680`00394f28 : nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault+0x10a
fffff880`060ef760 fffff800`02ef006b : fffffa80`0aeff270 fffffa80`0efb1578     00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+0x36e
fffff880`060ef7e0 fffff800`02edcc8f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff680`003b5818 fffffa80`0efb1578 : nt!MiResolveTransitionFault+0x16b
fffff880`060ef870 fffff800`02ecc179 : 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff fffffa80`0f946060 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDispatchFault+0x95f
fffff880`060ef980 fffff800`02ebdcee : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001dedf8 fffff880`060efa01 00000000`00000007 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x359
fffff880`060efae0 00000000`772fe2be : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x16e
00000000`0328fa18 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x772fe2be


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+36e
fffff800`02ed05ce 49890cc0        mov     qword ptr [r8+rax*8],rcx

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4
SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+36e
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: nt
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  531590fb
IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18409
IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1E_c0000005_R_nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+36e
BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1E_c0000005_R_nt!MiUnlinkPageFromLockedList+36e
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x1e_c0000005_r_nt!miunlinkpagefromlockedlist+36e
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {3264b3ba-cf19-fae1-16b7-0f69c15b38b9}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

---

Comment: remove F-Secure ad if you still get a crash test the RAM with memtest86+: http://www.memtest.org/#downiso

Comment: Turns out that F-secure was guilty of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there are two important things to know when analyzing a blue screen.

a) As you found out: the `PROCESS_NAME:  fsgk32.exe`

If it cannot directly be associated with a product, a Google search will usually give some hints. You found out F-Secure, which Google also indicates.

b) The type of the problem, which is `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED` in this case.

This becomes a bit tricky, since there are problems which immediately lead to a blue screen, such as an exception in kernel mode (this one) but there are also other problems, e.g. memory leaks, which can go undetected for a while and then crash later.

In your case, it is an immediate blue screen, so the process name is typically correct. You verified this by uninstalling in safe mode, I assume.

In that latter case (memory leak), the listed process name is not correct and other measures need to be taken. There might be different approaches for delayed crashes. I use driver verifier, which comes with Windows (Win+R, `verifier.exe`). You may want to read about it before using it, since it can be cumbersome to turn it off if results in crashes during boot time.